# LinkedIn incorrect link image

Tags: html, css, linkedin-api

I'm trying to link a website of mine to the featured section of LinkedIn. When I added the site it linked a Facebook logo. Facebook is a link on my menu of the website.

This is the mega tag  I created, which should be the link on LinkedIn. -

My website address is - http://collteq.com/walrus.html

Has anyone any idea what I'm doing wrong, as I'm totally baffled!

Best wishes

Dan

```css
#topbar {
 
width:1000px;
 
margin:0 auto;
 
height:105px;
 
}
 
body {
 
margin: 0;
 
padding: 0;
 
font-family: arial;
 
}
 
#walrus-text {
 
font-weight: bold;
 
font-size:400%;
 
margin-top:15px;
 
 
/*  REMOVED margin-left:323px;*/
 
}
 
#beatlesfansite-text {
 
    font-weight: bold;
 
    font-size:120%;
    
    padding-bottom:10px;
    
 
    /*  REMOVED position:relative;
    
    left:570px;
    
    bottom:15px;*/
  
}
 
#facebook, #twitter, #spotify, #youtube, #itunes, #email{
 
margin-top:35px;
 
margin-left:31px;
 
height:37px;
 
}
 
 
#youtube {
 
height:41px;
 
}
 
 
#itunes {
 
height:34px;
 
}
 
 
#email {
 
height:31px;
 
}
 
 
 
#page-container {
 
width:1000px;
 
margin:0 auto;
 
}
 
#fabfour {
 
width:730px; 
 
/* REMOVED margin:0px 280px;
 
height:720px;*/
 
}
 
.container {
 
width:360px;
 
height:360px;
 
position:relative;
 
margin: 0 0 0 5px;
 
float:left;
 
}
 
#beatle-paul, #beatle-george, #beatle-john, #beatle-ringo, #paul, #george, #john, #ringo {
 
width:350px;
 
height:350px;
 
}
 
.overlay {
 
position: absolute; 
 
left:0px;
 
top:0;
 
opacity: 0;
 
transition: .5s ease;
 
}
 
.overlay:hover {
 
opacity: 1;
 
}
 
.clear {
    
    clear:both;
    
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>The Walrus</title>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta property="og:title" content="The Walrus" />
 <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
 <meta name="image" property="og:image" content="[http://collteq.com/images/george.jpg]">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
 <meta name="Description" content="This is a Beatles fan site, which contains information on the solo careers of John Lennon, Paul McCartney, George Harrion and Ringo Starr."/>
 <meta property='og:url' content='//http://collteq.com/walrus.html'/>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="walrus.css">
 
<style>
 
#topbar {
    width:1000px;  /* changed */
    margin:0 auto;
    height:105px;
}
 
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: arial;
}
 
#walrus-text {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:400%;
    margin-top:15px;
    /*margin-left:323px;*/
}
 
#beatlesfansite-text {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:120%;
    padding-bottom:10px; /*added */
    /*position:relative;
    left:570px;
    bottom:15px;*/
}
 
#facebook, #twitter, #spotify, #youtube, #itunes, #email{
    margin-top:35px;
    margin-left:31px;
    height:37px;
}
 
#youtube {
  height:41px;
}
 
#itunes {
    height:34px;
}
 
#email {
height:31px;
}
 
 
 
#page-container {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
 
#fabfour {
    width:730px; /* changed */
    /*margin:0px 280px;
    height:720px;  changed */
}
 
.container {
    width:360px; /* changed */
    height:360px; /* changed */
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    float:left;
}
 
#beatle-paul, #beatle-george, #beatle-john, #beatle-ringo, #paul, #george, #john, #ringo {
    width:350px;
    height:350px;
}
 
.overlay {
    position: absolute; 
    left:0px;
    top:0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
}
 
.overlay:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.clear {  /*added */
    clear:both;
}
 
</style>
 
</head>
 
<body>
 
<div id="topbar">
 
    <span id="walrus-text">THE WALRUS</span>
 
    <a href="https://en-gb.facebook.com/thebeatles"><img id="facebook" src= "images/facebook.PNG"></a>
 
    <a href="https://twitter.com/thebeatles"><img id="twitter" src= "images/twitter.PNG"></a>
 
    <a href="https://open.spotify.com/artist/3WrFJ7ztbogyGnTHbHJFl2"><img id="spotify" src= "images/spotify.PNG"></a>
 
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=beatles"><img id="youtube" src= "images/youtube.PNG"></a>
 
    <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/the-beatles/136975"><img id="itunes" src= "images/itunes.PNG"></a>
 
    <a href="https://www.thebeatles.com/contact"><img id="email" src= "images/email.PNG"></a>
 
</div>
 
<div id="page-container"> <!-- added -->
 
    <div id="beatlesfansite-text">Beatles Fan Site</div>
 
    <div id="fabfour">  
 
        <div class="container">
 
            <img id="beatle-george" src= "images/beatlegeorge.jpg">
 
            <div class="overlay">
 
                <a href="walrus-george.html"><img id="george" src="images/george.jpg"></a>
 
            </div>
 
        </div>
 
        <div class="container">
 
            <img id="beatle-paul" src= "images/beatlepaul.jpg">
 
            <div class="overlay">
 
                <a href="walrus-paul.html"><img id="paul" src="images/paul.jpg"></a>
 
            </div>
 
        </div>
        
        <div class="clear"></div> <!-- added -->
        
        <div class="container">
 
            <img id="beatle-john" src= "images/beatlejohn.jpg">
 
            <div class="overlay">
 
                <a href="walrus-john.html"><img id="john" src="images/john.jpg"></a>
 
            </div>
 
        </div>
 
        <div class="container">
 
            <img id="beatle-ringo" src= "images/beatleringo.jpg">
 
            <div class="overlay">
 
<a href="walrus-ringo.html"><img id="ringo" src="images/ringo.jpg"></a>
 
            </div>
            
        </div>
         
    </div>
 
</div>
 
</body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: add the linkedin.png file to the images folder on the server.  and add this after contact <a> tag
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/user"><img id="linkedin" src= "images/linked.PNG"></a>

Comment: Hi Kashif

Thanks for the reply, but I don't understand it. I'm new to coding, so i'm struggling at the moment. You've written that i should add a linkedin.png to the images folder on the server, and to add it after contact. I haven't written any contact code, so i don't understand what you mean. Can you explain?

Best wishes

Dan

Comment: please send me Linkedin URL

Comment: I've deleted the menu links as I though they might be the issue. However, it hasn't solved it as the image I've chosen still doesn't appear in the Featured section of LinkedIn. This is the meta tag for the image I want to use.  <meta name="image" property="og:image" content="[http://collteq.com/images/george.jpg]"> LinkedIn url - https://www.linkedin.com/in/daniel-collinson-aaaaa6b7/

Answer (score 0):

try this I had added a static CDN path of the LinkedIn icon URL.

```css
#topbar {
 
width:1000px;
 
margin:0 auto;
 
height:105px;
 
}
 
body {
 
margin: 0;
 
padding: 0;
 
font-family: arial;
 
}
 
#walrus-text {
 
font-weight: bold;
 
font-size:400%;
 
margin-top:15px;
 
 
/*  REMOVED margin-left:323px;*/
 
}
 
#beatlesfansite-text {
 
    font-weight: bold;
 
    font-size:120%;
    
    padding-bottom:10px;
    
 
    /*  REMOVED position:relative;
    
    left:570px;
    
    bottom:15px;*/
  
}
 
#facebook, #twitter, #spotify, #youtube, #itunes, #email{
 
margin-top:35px;
 
margin-left:31px;
 
height:37px;
 
}
 
 
#youtube {
 
height:41px;
 
}
 
 
#itunes {
 
height:34px;
 
}
 
 
#email {
 
height:31px;
 
}
 
 
 
#page-container {
 
width:1000px;
 
margin:0 auto;
 
}
 
#fabfour {
 
width:730px; 
 
/* REMOVED margin:0px 280px;
 
height:720px;*/
 
}
 
.container {
 
width:360px;
 
height:360px;
 
position:relative;
 
margin: 0 0 0 5px;
 
float:left;
 
}
 
#beatle-paul, #beatle-george, #beatle-john, #beatle-ringo, #paul, #george, #john, #ringo {
 
width:350px;
 
height:350px;
 
}
 
.overlay {
 
position: absolute; 
 
left:0px;
 
top:0;
 
opacity: 0;
 
transition: .5s ease;
 
}
 
.overlay:hover {
 
opacity: 1;
 
}
 
.clear {
    
    clear:both;
    
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>The Walrus</title>

 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta property="og:title" content="The Walrus" />
 <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
 <meta name="image" property="og:image" content="[http://collteq.com/images/george.jpg]">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
 <meta name="Description" content="This is a Beatles fan site, which contains information on the solo careers of John Lennon, Paul McCartney, George Harrion and Ringo Starr."/>
 <meta property='og:url' content='//http://collteq.com/walrus.html'/>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="walrus.css">
 
<style>
 
#topbar {
    width:1000px;  /* changed */
    margin:0 auto;
    height:105px;
}
 
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: arial;
}
 
#walrus-text {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:400%;
    margin-top:15px;
    /*margin-left:323px;*/
}
 
#beatlesfansite-text {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:120%;
    padding-bottom:10px; /*added */
    /*position:relative;
    left:570px;
    bottom:15px;*/
}
 
#facebook, #twitter, #spotify, #youtube, #itunes, #email{
    margin-top:35px;
    margin-left:31px;
    height:37px;
}
 
#youtube {
  height:41px;
}
 
#itunes {
    height:34px;
}
 
#email {
height:31px;
}
 
 
 
#page-container {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
 
#fabfour {
    width:730px; /* changed */
    /*margin:0px 280px;
    height:720px;  changed */
}
 
.container {
    width:360px; /* changed */
    height:360px; /* changed */
    position:relative;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px;
    float:left;
}
 
#beatle-paul, #beatle-george, #beatle-john, #beatle-ringo, #paul, #george, #john, #ringo {
    width:350px;
    height:350px;
}
 
.overlay {
    position: absolute; 
    left:0px;
    top:0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .5s ease;
}
 
.overlay:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.clear {  /*added */
    clear:both;
}
 
</style>
 
</head>
 
<body>
 
<div id="topbar">
 
    <span id="walrus-text">THE WALRUS</span>
 
    <a href="https://en-gb.facebook.com/thebeatles"><img id="facebook" src= "images/facebook.PNG"></a>
 
    <a href="https://twitter.com/thebeatles"><img id="twitter" src= "images/twitter.PNG"></a>
 
    <a href="https://open.spotify.com/artist/3WrFJ7ztbogyGnTHbHJFl2"><img id="spotify" src= "images/spotify.PNG"></a>
 
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=beatles"><img id="youtube" src= "images/youtube.PNG"></a>
 
    <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/the-beatles/136975"><img id="itunes" src= "images/itunes.PNG"></a>

<a href="https://be.linkedin.com/company/the-beatles"><img id="itunes" src= "https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/2428/PNG/512/linkedin_black_logo_icon_147114.png"></a>
 
    <a href="https://www.thebeatles.com/contact"><img id="email" src= "images/email.PNG"></a>
 
</div>
 
<div id="page-container"> <!-- added -->
 
    <div id="beatlesfansite-text">Beatles Fan Site</div>
 
    <div id="fabfour">  
 
        <div class="container">
 
            <img id="beatle-george" src= "images/beatlegeorge.jpg">
 
            <div class="overlay">
 
                <a href="walrus-george.html"><img id="george" src="images/george.jpg"></a>
 
            </div>
 
        </div>
 
        <div class="container">
 
            <img id="beatle-paul" src= "images/beatlepaul.jpg">
 
            <div class="overlay">
 
                <a href="walrus-paul.html"><img id="paul" src="images/paul.jpg"></a>
 
            </div>
 
        </div>
        
        <div class="clear"></div> <!-- added -->
        
        <div class="container">
 
            <img id="beatle-john" src= "images/beatlejohn.jpg">
 
            <div class="overlay">
 
                <a href="walrus-john.html"><img id="john" src="images/john.jpg"></a>
 
            </div>
 
        </div>
 
        <div class="container">
 
            <img id="beatle-ringo" src= "images/beatleringo.jpg">
 
            <div class="overlay">
 
<a href="walrus-ringo.html"><img id="ringo" src="images/ringo.jpg"></a>
 
            </div>
            
        </div>
         
    </div>
 
</div>
 
</body>
 
</html>
```